# Synergy System tray is unavailable, quitting

Tags: release-freya

I have just installed Elementary OS Freya. I was using Ubuntu 15.10 with Gnome before this. Synergy was working just fine with that.

But now I since I have installed the .deb file Synergy crashes with the message 
 ***System tray is unavailable, quitting*** . Please help me. Synergy is very important for me. I share my mouse + keyboard with Macbook and Linux laptop

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in a missinig package: sni-qt

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt
```

after that command it works. Reference: https://github.com/synergy/synergy/issues/4774

Answer credit [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/2z50ch/has_anyone_had_any_luck_with_synergy_on_freya/)